# locate function symbol from where (object or library)

Tags: gcc

As we know, we could dump some info by objdump like:
objdump -t u_binary

00000000040e2390 l     F .text  000000000000001d              _ZNK10QTcpServer11errorStringEv

Then we know it's a function symbol.
But I want to know it comes from which object file or library.

Depends on 'ld' or 'gcc'?

Thanks,